# Google Search Console not returning aggregate numbers

Tags: python, google-api, google-search-console

I've set up the connection to the Google Search Console API to reduce the amount of manual extracts we have to do. However, I can't get it to pull the aggregates -- essentially the big topline numbers when you go to "search results" in the platform and test a query using "queries containing" like you see here:

[image]

For example, this is my payload:

```
payload = {
  "startDate": "2024-01-01",
  "endDate": "2024-01-31",
  "dimensions": ["MYQUERY"],
  "dimensionFilterGroups": [
    {
      "filters": [
        {
          "dimension": "query",
          "operator": "contains",
          "expression": "query"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "responseAggregationType": "byProperty"
}
```

CoPilot tells me there should be a field called "responseAggregationTypeRows" that contains total clicks, total impressions, average ctr and average position. However, that field is not there. The closest is a repeat of "responseAggregationType": "byProperty". Instead, this is what the API returns.

```
{'rows': [{'keys': ['Query 1'],
   'clicks': 52,
   'impressions': 83,
   'ctr': 0.6265060240963856,
   'position': 1.072289156626506},
  {'keys': ['Query 2'],
   'clicks': 7,
   'impressions': 2883,
   'ctr': 0.002428026361429067,
   'position': 46.153659382587584},
  {'keys': ["Query 3"],
   'clicks': 2,
   'impressions': 2,
   'ctr': 1,
   'position': 4.5},
  ...],
 'responseAggregationType': 'byProperty'}
```

(Note: I've truncated the API content above for readability. Everything in "rows" is a query that contains the words from my API call.)

I've also tried changing the aggregation type to "byPage" or "auto", but that doesn't fix things. Obviously, I could loop through this but would prefer to grab straight from the API if Google already has it.

Comment: But that response contains exactly the same information as the results in your screenshot, right?  7, 2.88k, 0.2%, 46.2.

Comment: The image is just for illustration. In actuality, the screenshot is with "exact query" selected because it's what I happened to have on screen at the time. That's why it matches the first query exactly. My Python script uses a contains, which is why I need the aggregates. I wouldn't need aggregates if I was using "exact query" because there would be only one set of results.

Comment: The I have no idea what the problem is.  You said it shows you results that you don't see in the API, but you have certainly not demonstrated that there is a problem.